# Regarding derivation of $(A \cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm working on some HW and having some trouble understanding what the question is asking. 
The questions is as follows:

> Supply a reason for each step in the derivation. 
>   $$(A \cup  B) \cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$$
>
> *Proof*: 
>   \begin{align*}
> (A \cup  B) \cap C &=  C \cap (A \cup  B) & \text{by: (a)}\\
> &= (C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B) & \text{by: (b)}\\
> &= (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) & \text{by: (c)}
> \end{align*}

I understand that $C \cap (A \cup B)$ can become $(C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B)$ because of the distributive law, but I'm not sure what it means, "by: (a)".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the (a), (b), and (c) are just question "numbers"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it means that when you write your answer paper, you should say something like "(a) is the distributive law" and similarly for (b) and (c).

Comment: Ya that seemed to simple, I think maybe I was confused because a,b,c are also variables.

Comment: Mathematicians will never use a lowercase 'a' to mean the same thing as an uppercase 'a'.

Comment: Oh good point I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @MYANSWERSARECRAP I disagree; just because I have used $a$ for something, does that mean I have effectively eliminated the possibility to use $A,\mathcal{A},\mathfrak{A},\mathbb{A},\ldots$?

Comment: I didn't say they wouldn't use both; I said they wouldn't use them both *to mean the same thing*.